# html5 video player not working in Phonegap Android 2.2?

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Here is the html code:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" class="my-page" id="video">
 <video id="video_tag" src="#" controls="controls"></video>
 </div>
```

in js code:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#video", function () {
     $('#video_tag').attr('src',data[curYear].video.url);
    });
```

`data[curYear].video.url = videos/1970.mp4`     this is the path already set in my root folder
same code is working in browser but i am not getting any video in android tablet version 2.2 using phonegap android can anyone explain what is the issue?

Comment: have you set type attribute `type="video/mp4"`

Comment: at which place i need to set

Comment: `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#video", function () {
     $('#video_tag').attr({'src':data[curYear].video.url,'type':'video/mp4'}); 
    });`

Comment: no luck no video seen

Comment: only android? on which browser? please add all relevant info.

Comment: i m playing in android tablet GT-P1000 and android 2.2   no video seen there while same code is working in my system's FF browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <video width="356" height="200" controls poster="full/http/link/to/image/file.png"  >

    <source src="full/link/to/http/mp4/video/file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

    <source src="full/link/to/http/ogv/video/file.ogv" type="video/ogg" />

    <source src="full/link/to/http/webm/video/file.wbem" type="video/webm" />

    <em>Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</em>

    </video>
```

Comment: i need to change video source dynamically on button click

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet. Hope it helps. If not, pls describe the error.

```
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" class="my-page" id="video">

     </div>

 var url = data[curYear].video.url;
    var videotag = '<video id="video_tag" controls preload="none">'+
                               '<source src="'+url+'" type="video/mp4" /><em>Your browser does not support the video file.</em>
                               '</video>';

 $('#video').html(videotag);
```

Comment: var url1 = data[curYear].video.url;
   var videotag = '<video id="video_tag" controls preload="none">'+
   '<source src="'+url1+'" type="video/mp4"/><em>Your browser does not support the video file.</em>'</video>';                                                                                                                                        getting error :   01-03 22:40:48.198: E/Web Console(13297): Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing / at file:///android_asset/www/js/adidas.js:54


 $('#video_div').html(videotag);

Comment: error resolves but still no video seen in  video page in android device 2.2   while same code is showing and playing video in browser but failed to do in device